# Google Apps Script - searching through an array doesn't return text values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm finding it really hard to word my question correctly into google.

I'm in the process of writing a Google Apps script that will search through a column of data to see if there's a match.

When I put the values into an array, the return is

[ 'data' ]

rather than an actual string.  This means that I'll never find a match.

I thought it was because I was searching through a list of numbers stored as text (all Australian mobile phone numbers have a leading "0"), so I tried different columns with the same result.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Code excerpt:

```
//Global variables - spreadsheet name, sheet names
const This_File = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
const Code_Sheet = This_File.getSheetByName("Button");
const Data_Sheet = This_File.getSheetByName("Current_Members");
  
  function search_ph_num() {
    //find last row of data
    var last_row = Data_Sheet.getLastRow()
    var rng_map = "C2:C"+last_row
    //var rng_map = "A2:A"+last_row;

    console.log(rng_map)


    //testing
    //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(rng_map);

    //testing, input dummy data - will be read from email list
    var dummy_array = ["0412345678", "033999779", "0455667"];

    // first number should be found value
    
    //set search range to phone number column
    var this_range = Data_Sheet.getRange(rng_map);
   
1. 
1. var Skt_Number = this_range.getValues();
1. 
1.     //search phone numbers for existing data. Assume phone number is unique... pretty valid assumption.
1. 
1. for (var i = 0; i <= last_row; i = i + 1){
1. 
1. var isMatched = dummy_array.indexOf(Skt_Number[i]); 

        
        
        if (isMatched !== -1) {

//SNIP  actual code goes here
          SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(Skt_Number[i]);
          SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(i + 2);
        }

        //debug
        
        if (Skt_Number[i] == "0412345678"){
          var insert_dummy = Data_Sheet.getRange("I3");

          insert_dummy.setValue(Skt_Number[i]);

          console.log(Skt_Number[i])

          var insert_dummy = Data_Sheet.getRange("J3");

          insert_dummy.setValue(dummy_array[0]);

          console.log(dummy_array[0])

        }

        
        
    }

    
  }
```

Log output:

```
2:08:04 PM  Notice  Execution started
2:08:05 PM  Info    C2:C11
2:08:05 PM  Info    [ '0412345678' ]
2:08:05 PM  Info    0412345678
2:08:05 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

So, [ '0412345678' ] will never match 0412345678.

What am I doing wrong?

Input cell data into an array. Tried to search array using indexOf method. Expected to find match. No match returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your showing script, I guessed that the reason for your current issue is due to `Skt_Number` of `var Skt_Number = this_range.getValues();` is a 2-dimensional array.

About `So, [ '0412345678' ] will never match 0412345678.`, I think that `[ '0412345678' ]` is a 1-dimensional array. And, `0412345678` is a string value. And, `Array.prototype.indexOf()` can be used for a 1-dimensional array. If you want to compare them, how about modifying as follows.

#### From:

```
var isMatched = dummy_array.indexOf(Skt_Number[i]);
```

#### To:

```
var isMatched = dummy_array.indexOf(Skt_Number[i][0]);
```

- In your range, only one column is used with `var rng_map = "C2:C"+last_row`. So, `Skt_Number` is like `[["value1"],["value2"],,,]`. So, I modified `Skt_Number[i]` to `Skt_Number[i][0]`.

#### Reference:

- [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Seems to have worked. I don't fully understand your answer just yet, but it seems to have worked. Kudos and thanks